# Regex rejects every email

Tags: regex, vb.net

I am using the following code in my "Continue" button to check an email address text field.

```
        If Regex.IsMatch(txtEmail.Text, "^(?("")("".+?(?<!\\)""@)|(([0-9a-z]((\.(?!\.))|[-!#\$%&'\*\+/=\?\^`\{\}\|~\w])*)(?<=[0-9a-z])@)) (?(\[)(\[(\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}\])|(([0-9a-z][-\w]*[0-9a-z]*\.)+[a-z0-9][\-a-z0-9]{0,22}[a-z0-9]))$",
             (RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)) Then
        pnlInvalidEmail.Visible = False
    Else
        pnlInvalidEmail.Visible = True
        Exit Sub
    End If
```

The problem I am having is that the Regex (pinched from [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/01escwtf(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1)) is checking the textbox, but nothing is passing the check. No matter what I put in the text field, it fails the check and my warning panel appears.

Where am I going wrong? Apart from trying to validate emails using regex?

Comment: Try this `"^[_a-z0-9-]+(.[a-z0-9-]+)@[a-z0-9-]+(.[a-z0-9-]+)*(.[a-z]{2,4})$"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would change your regex since it's really difficult to troubleshoot it.

I would use another regex like:

```
^\w+[.\w]*@\w+([.]\w+)([.][a-z]{2,3})?$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/oT9mR0/1)**

Answer (score 1):

Try this..

```
"^[_a-z0-9-]+(.[a-z0-9-]+)@[a-z0-9-]+(.[a-z0-9-]+)*(.[a-z]{2,4})$"
```

Comment: You have to escape the dot by doing `\.` or `[.]` :)

Comment: This one works for most addresses but for some reason didn't approve of my personal email me@server.net, there's no extra punctuation or anything in my email so I don't see why it failed. Bit weird.

Comment: @ChrisHinton that's because the last part of the pattern `(.[a-z]{2,4})` it should be used as optional by doing `(.[a-z]{2,4})?`

Answer (score 0):

Must be a custom email regex.  I won't try to give you a better one,
but will try to help you understand why its not letting anything through.

If you focus on this section
you can see the problem. Basically this assertion `(?<= [0-9a-z] )` only lets one form in -
a single alphanum char then  the @ symbol.

```
   |  (?:
           (?:
                [0-9a-z] 
                (?:
                     (?:
                          \.
                          (?! \. )
                     )
                  |  [-!#\$%&'\*\+/=\?\^`\{\}\|~\w] 
                )*
           )
           (?<= [0-9a-z] )
           @
      )
```

And clearly from the regex conditionals, they allow matching `".."@` and `[..]@` as well.
Just using another vanilla regex won't allow that.